# Unit tests in C# with xUnit: why setting invariant culture works in base class but not in fixture?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I want to set invariant culture for my test cases, at a test class level.
What I did first is to create a base class for test classes, but it is instantiated for every test case, so culture is set/rollbacked for every test, what I do not need.

So I replaced the base class by a class fixture (xUnit 2.4.1), which is instantiated once for the test class (good, as expected) but... **the culture set is not taken into account**. From the very first test case, even in the ctor of the test class (which is called after fixture's one), the culture is my system's one and not the one I have set to tests.

I have checked that both fixture and test case are running in the same thread.

Fixture is very basic and looks like this:

```cs
public class UnitTestsFixture : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposedValue;
    protected readonly CultureInfo originalCulture;

    public UnitTestsFixture()
    {
        originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
            // TODO: set large fields to null
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is relying on the ambient culture, **it's wrong**. You should be constructing the desired culture object as necessary, and passing that object to the formatting methods you call to display culture-sensitive information. Further, if your code is backend code, it should not be doing any culture formatting at all - the frontend code should be doing that.

Comment: To answer the actual question though, the most likely explanation is that something in your code is overriding the culture being set.

Comment: As noted on the anser of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73390734/xunit-custom-useculture-attribute-does-the-sample-attribute-contain-any-issues and the package it links a) there is a sample b) in general the correct time to set/rest the culture is immediately before/after a test as xUnit has vatious phases of processing which can be in different execution contexts / threads - i.e. your dispose may not be guaranteed to be on the correct thread c) there may be official support in V3, see discussion near top of https://www.google.com/search?q=culturedfact

Comment: @IanKemp while I agree with the general spirit of not being culture sensitive in your backend, not mucking with the env and instead being explicit if you're testing things, for UI code in a frontend app, having culture sensitive code may be correct, and chaining the culture inward can wind up extremely messy indeed, which is why CulturedFact exists

Comment: "I want to set invariant culture for my test cases, at a test class level." - for avoidance of doubt, please note that [the fixture is created for every test execution](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html). In terms of how to use the same, best is to make a `const` for the culture and then ref that in your CulturedFact per test

Comment: The so called "duplicate question" has nothing of a duplicate but hey, random admin has decided so. Thanks for the attempts of answers anyways!